# sfdx force:source:retrieve doesn't work for account field

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

Does anybody knows why this works for field `Origin` of `Case` SObject:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadata "StandardValueSet:CaseOrigin"`

and this doesn't work for field `AccountSource` of `Account` SObject?

`sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadata "StandardValueSet:AccountAccountSource"`

- both fields are standard fields
- both fields have custom values

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AccountSource` is not the name of a StandardValueSet. I think you want `LeadSource` which is used on the Account

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm

Comment: you're the best man!!! Thank you so much!